# How come cd doesn't work in my shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, amazon-ec2

SOLVED

I'm trying to make a shell script on my Linux Amazon-EC2 server that will start my Minecraft server but the cd command says it can't find the directory or file when I try to change to the directory the server executable is in.  Please note I have next to no experience with shell script of any kind.  Does it have to with permissions in the folder this file is located in or the file itself?  The file is named "startServer".

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ec2-user/Minecraft
java -Xmx2048M -Xms2048M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui
```

*I did not save it with a file extension. Should I? Does it need to be?

Comment: whats the output of: ls -l ~

Comment: Is there a `MineCraft` directory inside your home directory?  That's what sashang is getting at.

Comment: I copy and pasted this so I don't give you a lack of info: total 4
drwxrwxr-x 3 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Apr 27 00:30 Minecraft

Comment: Yes the the directory "Minecraft" does it exist.

Comment: are you sure it's the cd command that's not working and not your java command complaining about a missing minecraft_server.jar. It would help if you posted the exact text of the error instead of describing it.

Comment: 176% sure of it ;) I changed permissions of Minecraft folder didnt change anything

Comment: it is the cd command because the java command gives a different error (obviously because it cant find minecraft_server.jar) heres the text: No such file or directory
: No such file or directoryome/ec2-user/Minecraft
Unable to access jarfile minecraft_server.jar

Comment: Might be a good idea to copy and paste both the command and also the output that will make it easier for us to troubleshoot. And put it as a code clock in the question rather that in one of these comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make a script runnable you need to modify the permissions on the script so that it is executable.

The command to change permissions on Linux or UNIX is [chmod.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)

```
chmod +x ./name_of_your_script
```

Will grant the current user permission to execute the script.

The #! at the start of your script indicates to the interactive shell that the script is to be interpreted by /bin/bash so you do not really need add an extention to the file name. However, it is a common convention to append .sh to shell scripts.

Comment: should I use script or the name of the file?

Comment: chmod: cannot access `./script\r': No such file or directory
: No such file or directoryome/ec2-user/Minecraft
Unable to access jarfile minecraft_server.jar

Comment: Sorry you should use the name of the file.

Comment: Hang on, where did the '\r' come from?  Do you have some weird mix of unix and windows systems, or mistaken compensation therefore, going on?  Are you editing the script on one system and pushing it to another, or storing it on a foreign filesystem?

Comment: @Chris I am creating the file using WinVi I have remote access to the amazon-ec2 server, do I need to do something special?

Comment: It looks like you might be confusing the linux system with extraneous carriage return characters - it's very surprising that those are showing up inside the *quoted* portion of the error.  There are tools to clean that up, but can you just re-enter the script by hand using vi (or whatever) running on the linux system itself?

Comment: There is a difference between how lines in a file are terminated on Windows and Linux. That's why you are getting the carriage return character in there. If you want to continur using WinVi you could check the settings of the editor so that you saved the file as a UNIX file with UNIX line termination. I'll look that up.

Comment: ty that sounds like a likely error, finally something that sounds solid

Comment: I just had a hunt around for how to modify the settings on WinVi but to no avail. Have you considered using vim or Notepad++?

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I made a new file changed to UNIX settings and rewrote and it works just fine.  I'd like to apologize to everyone I didnt mention the WinVI editing before, thank you Rob.

Comment: No worries! @ChrisStratton was the one who spotted the carriage return character.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the error message?  My guess is that it is:

```
cd: /Minecraft: No such file or directory
```

This will happen if HOME is undefined, and ~ expands to the empty string.

Comment: : No such file or directoryome/ec2-user/Minecraft
Unable to access jarfile minecraft_server.jar

Comment: Try using the full path instead of the tilda, like `cd /home/user/Minecraft`.

Comment: It looks like $HOME is not set properly.  As gpojd suggests, stop using the tilde.

Comment: Didn't work same error: : No such file or directoryme/ec2-user/Minecraft
Unable to access jarfile minecraft_server.jar

Comment: cd .. doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

The script will need execute permissions to be able to run it; to do this, cd to the directory is stored and use:

```
chmod u+rwx startServer
```

I don't think this is your problem though.  Try using the full path to the minecraft_server.jar file rather than using cd:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -Xmx2048M -Xms2048M -jar /full/path/to/Minecraft/minecraft_server.jar nogui
```

Comment: I tried that earlier and it worked but it ran the jar in the directory the shell script was in and I want the jar to run in the Minecraft directory.

Comment: I changed permissions still doesnt work maybe I'm reading your instructions incorrectly

Comment: How about changing where you cd to: `cd /fullpath/to/Minecraft`

Comment: tried it, same error

Comment: copy the cd command from your script and run it in the terminal. Does it give the same error?  If so, the directory doesn't exist.  I know it sounds stupid but is it definitely Minecraft and not minecraft?

Comment: that works but it runs the jar in the directory the bash file is in

Comment: cd in the terminal worked just fine